# Layout-align in md-grid-tile not working for me

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have this example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqqdYR

I want to basically separate the divs, so that they are evenly spaced inside the `md-grid-tile`. I am trying to follow this reference: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment, using:

```
layout="row" layout-align="space-between center"
```

But this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing layout with grids. To achieve what you are looking for use the following code:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols="3" md-row-height="1:0.1" md-gutter="12px">
  <md-grid-tile style="background:green">
    <div>This should</div>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile style="background:green">
    <div>be</div>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile style="background:green">
    <div>spaced</div>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

The number of cols is defined by "md-cols" and the gutter between the tiles with "md-gutter" (1px if not specified). Then each tile has to be defined in a "md-grid-tile"

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked this 8 months ago, however I was having the same issue with the md-grid-tile today. Modified your codepen and added in another div to wrap the content, making sure to specify flex="100". See [Forked Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNpPjp)

```html
 <md-grid-list md-cols="1" md-row-height="1:0.1" style="background:green">
    <md-grid-tile >
      <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center"  flex="100" >
        <div >This should</div>
        <div >be</div>
        <div >spaced</div>
      </div>
    </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
```